# how to join 4 or more tables in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 4 tables in the database:

1- users (id, name, email, password)

2- services (id, name, price)

3- coupons (id, discount, expired_data, statue)

the last one is (pivot table) for the payment which connects all these tables together

4- payments (id, user_id, services_id, coupon_id, after_discount, total_paid)

my question here, how to join all these tables in a relationship using Laravel Eloquent to select, insert, update, and delete **(payments) table**. is it good to use many to many relationships?

thank you.

Comment: Is there any relationship between "coupons" and "services"?

Comment: there is no a relationship between them

Answer (score 0):

### Step - 1

Update table field

1- users (id, name, email, password)

2- services (id,user_id, name, price)

3- coupons (id,user_id discount, expired_data, statue)

4- payments (id, user_id, services_id, coupon_id, after_discount, total_paid)

### Step - 2

Add in User Model

```
    public function service(){
        return $this->hasMany(Service::class);
    }
    public function coupon(){
        return $this->hasMany(Coupon::class);
    }
    public function payment(){
        return $this->hasMany(Pay::class);
    }
```

### Step - 3

Get relational data

```
User::with(['service','payment','coupon'])->findOrFail($id);
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but in my application, services can't take any user, cuz it is just the services category. and for coupons, it can be used by many users not only one